# Editable DIV with clickable hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got the 1st part working of creating a div that contains clickable hyperlinks.

HTML:

```
<div id="input" contenteditable>

<div contentEditable="false">

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a> - <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit W3Schools</a> - <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Visit W3Schools</a>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 lightgray inset;  
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 398px;    
}
```

Per above code, i have a DIV that looks like an editable field containing 3 hyperlinks that user can click and navigate to corresponding pages.

And that part works fine.

Now what i want is, i want this DIV to be editable so that user can manually enter another hyperlink and click on a button and this new hyperlink will also be shown as a clickable item in the DIV along with the already existing 3.

Also user should be able to delete an already existing hyperlink.

How to do that?

Comment: You seem to have a good grasp of what you want. What is the part that you're stuck with? I would recommend taking a look at the `Selection` API. You don't need it to do what you want to do but if you want to ensure you can do it without moving the cursor you'll need it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Comment: What do you have so far?  Put another way, which part are you struggling with?  Making the field editable?  Saving the contents?  Preventing people from putting in non-link items?  something else?

Comment: The cursor doesn't show up inside the main DIV. I want the cursor to be displayed inside main DIV (id-input), so that user can type in something there. At the same time user should be able to hit backspace button and delete existing hyperlink items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSFIDDLE** https://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/vg4m5tso/

You can add new items using .append(). In my example i create a new link from the text in a textbox, and

```
    $('selector').append(content);
```

You can delete items by selecting them and calling .remove(). Add a delete element next to the link, then add a click event handler:

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
        $(this).prev('a').remove();
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, and it seems like this is the only way of adding new items to the DIV rather than editing the DIV itself. One issue i see is, after adding a new link via "Add Link" button, it shows up as  a clickable hyper link, but it doesn't work. i.e., i cannot click on that new item and navigate to the page.

Comment: I was adding the links to the outer div, not the inner div where the rest of the links are. I updated the fiddle and it works now.